# Cannot see anything in Airflow DAG Graph View

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

The problem is, in Airflow Web-UI DAG Graph View, I cannot see anything - complete empty, but the Tree view works just fine.

The Graph View was all good before, don't know what happened.
I tried to clear all the browser cache, use different browsers, didn't work.

Do you guys have any ideas why this happen? Thank a lot.

Comment: Check the webserver logs for error messages, if there are any paste them here.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same issue today as well (only for our users who use Chrome) and found out that it was due to a bug in chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1049982

From a quick look at the code, when the DAG is rendered, it removes dummy edges using the array.render js function (which is broken in chromium latest release).

So if you are using Chrome (happens to us on version 80.0.3987.87) then it might break for you as well (depending on how much edges you have in your DAG).

To confirm that it's the same issue, you can make sure that it works fine with other browsers, such as Firefox or Safari.

There are a couple of possible solutions:

1. Downgrade Chrome to a lower version
2. Use a different browser
3. Apply the following (temporary) fix in one of Airflow's static file (if it's accessible to you):

**File Path**:

.../airflow/www/static/dagre-d3.js

**Code**:

```
...
module.exports = Renderer;

// Fix for https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1049982
//Start fix
(function() {
        const arrayReduce = Array.prototype.reduce;
        let callback;
        Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'reduce', {
                value: function(cb, ...args) {
                        callback = cb;
                        return arrayReduce.call(this, callback, ...args);
                }
        });
})();
//End fix

function Renderer() {
...
```

Comment: There is no file named `dagre-d3.js` in Airflow v2.1.0. I have the same problem and the same happens both on Chrome and Firefox. I have updated the Chrome from version 80 to version 91 but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Update Chrome version to **>=80.0.3987.149** .

Looks like the problem is only for Chrome on **80.0.3987.87** like @moshe-derri explained in his answer

Comment: I have updated the Chrome from version 80 to version 91 but no luck.